# Blackberry 7.1 Java app port to Blackberry 10

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-jde

Can I develop app for blackberry 7.1 in Java and then it is possible to port for Blackberry 10 also? I searched on internet so much but didn't find good answer. Any suggestions or opinions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I find it difficult to believe you did not find any information when searching.  Here are just a few of the places I found.  I recommend you start with the first one.

[port-java-to-cascades-part-1](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2013/01/port-java-to-cascades-part-1/)

[how-to-prepare-old-blackberry-app-for-blackberry-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914435/how-to-prepare-old-blackberry-app-for-blackberry-10)

[Porting BlackBerry Java Apps to BlackBerry 10 - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DD7UbveZgy4)

For more, search for 
"porting blackberry java apps to blackberry 10"

Good luck.